# Стоит ли объявлять геттеры и сеттеры __forceinline?

Tags: c++

Стоит ли объявлять геттеры и сеттеры `__forceinline`?

Comment: а смысл? производительность?

Comment: а уже профилировали? узнали, что это узкое место?

Comment: А как они выглядят?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Нет.

`__forceinline` можно использовать только если профилирование и анализ сгенерированного кода показал что оно может значительно улучшить производительность в каждом конкретном случае.

Comment: А что, компилятор запрещает его использовать, если не сделать профилирование?:)

Comment: @KoVadim, было бы не плохо, если бы компилятор запрещал что-то делать пока не сделано профилирование :-D

Comment: @Abyx, а разве встраиванием не всегда повышает производительность, за счет убирания вызова функции?

Comment: Почему все компиляторы игнорируют?